# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'element') when accessing event object

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

So I am using **Vue Draggable** and I am to access the event object in VueJs like below:

```
<draggable group="leads"
   :list="newLeads"
   @change="seeChange($event, 'New')">
```

In methods:

```
async seeChange(event, status) {

    console.log(event.added.element.id);

 await axios.patch('http://localhost/api/leads/'+event.added.element.id+'/update-status', 
{status : status}).then(response => {

        this.leads.unshift(response.data.data);
        
        this.getLeads();
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  },
```

I can see the id in the console. But when I drag the card (triggering the event) I get a

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'element')*

error when the card lands. Even the Axios call gets the correct id and the request is sent fine. But the white screen with this error appears nonetheless.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? What is it's solution?

Answer (score 1):

in vue 3 you should use draggable library as below:

install:

```
npm i -S vuedraggable@next
```

import:

```
import Draggable from 'vuedraggable';
```

and this is the link with full examples:
https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next

Answer (score 0):

`Change` event is called with one argument containing one of the following properties: `added`, `removed`, `moved`. [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable#events).

`event.added` contains information of an element added to the array but when you do `removed`, `moved` you haven't property `added` in object `event`.

You can use it like this:

```
async seeChange(event, status) {
    console.log(event?.added.element.id);

    if(event.added) {
           await axios.patch('http://localhost/api/leads/'+event.added.element.id+'/update-status', {status : status}).then(response => {
              this.leads.unshift(response.data.data);
              this.getLeads();
           }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
           });
    }
}
```

request will be send only after added event.

If you want to send request on each event you can do it
by using `Object.values(event)[0]`, example:

```
async seeChange(event, status) {
    const id = Object.values(event)[0].element.id;
    console.log(id);

           await axios.patch('http://localhost/api/leads/'+id+'/update-status', {status : status}).then(response => {
              this.leads.unshift(response.data.data);
              this.getLeads();
           }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
           });
    
}
```